# Detecting multiple instances of XBAP Application

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xbap

I have a XBAP application which I have published in IIS.

Let's say I run the application in the web browser, then open a new tab and run the application again.

1. How can I detect that more than one instance is running?
2. How can I force that only one instance should run?

Thanks in advance

Comment: XBAP is a WPF concept, Silverlight is a separate technology - can you clarify which you want?  The title, tags, and question body seem out of sync.

Comment: Possibly an over-zealous edit on my part there... apologies

Answer (score 1):

XBAP applications typically run in partial trust mode as well as in a "sandbox" of sorts.  Because of this limitation, your program will not be able to reach out and search for other instances of itself.  If you were to run in full trust, you may find yourself with more options.

Here is a bit from Microsoft about the sandbox to give you a better idea of your options.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480229.aspx

Comment: Thanks A R, In this above link i got something but i dint get the answer what i want ! :(